# Data rerenders only once onClick using function with filter() in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, render

I have a navigation bar with 3 buttons (not the main navbar) that should filter menu items onto Pizzas, Sides, Drinks when clicked. When I click either button it only shows one of the filtered menu (if I click Pizzas, it shows the list of different pizzas).

The issue is that it only works once, so if I click again or click Sides or Drinks, it doesn't show anything, just an empty page. I thought about using useEffect to re-render, but can't think of a way on how to use it.

How can I make each button show the different data/menu items when clicking each menu category (Pizzas, Sides, Drinks)?

```
const Menu = () => {
  const [menuList, setMenuList] = useState(initialMenuList);

  function eventMenuClick(e) {
    const nameSelection = e.currentTarget.textContent;

    setMenuList((menuList) => {
      return menuList.filter((item) => {
        if (item.category === nameSelection) {
          return console.log(item);
        }
        return null;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Menu</h1>
      <div className="nav-container">
        <ul className="menu-list">
          <li className="menutype" onClick={eventMenuClick}>Pizzas</li>
          <li className="menutype" onClick={eventMenuClick}>Sides</li>
          <li className="menutype" onClick={eventMenuClick}>Drinks</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <MenuList menuList={menuList} />
      <NavBar />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

```
const MenuList = ({ menuList }) => {
  return (
    <div className="menulist-container">
      {menuList.map((item) => (
        <MenuItem
          key={item.id}
          title={item.name}
          image={item.image}
          price1={item.priceM}
          price2={item.priceL}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuList;
```

Comment: Your filter always returns a falsy value. `return console.log(item)` returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your menu, you can have another state which contains only filtered values.

```
 const [menuList, setMenuList] = useState(initialMenuList);
 const [visibleMenu, setVisibleMenu] = useState(initialMenuList); // <- HERE

  function eventMenuClick(e) {
    const nameSelection = e.currentTarget.textContent;

    const filtered = menuList.filter((item) => item.category === nameSelection);
    setVisibleMenu(filtered);
  }
```

And when you render your list, instead of original data, use filtered to be rendered.

```
 <MenuList menuList={visibleMenu} />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so the main idea is to create an additional useState(). Another issue appearing because of this is that the page does not display the menu on the first render, however I solved that by setting setVisible(menuList) inside a useEffect().

Comment: Actually, that will force your component to render one more time since you are performing additional setVisible action. Instead, I suggest initializing visibleMenu with initialMenuList also, just like you did your menuList. I will update the answer, so you can see what I mean

Comment: I get it now, thanks once more! :)